# Firebase Analytics: Install Referrer: iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

Is there any way to get the app install referrer information via firebase for an iOS app.

Say there is a iOS app dynamic link with information about the source and campaign. And if the app is not installed, the link takes you to app store for installing the app.
After installing when opening the first time, is it possible to track the campaign source information via firebase.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, due to Apple dropping the referrer's URL when the user is taken to Apple Store to install the app for the first time, Firebase Analytics can't report campaign event and attribute it to the source/campaign. Firebase Dynamic Links can probably solve that issue. 
If users already install the app, and the URL opens the app directly with the link, then yes, Firebase Analytics can link to the source/campaign if the URL has utm_campaign or utm_source in the URL params.

Comment: can u share any link for that please

Comment: "Universal App Campaigns have only been available to run ads on Android. Now in beta, iOS developers can target users on YouTube, the Google Search App and the Google Display Network." https://marketingland.com/google-io-universal-app-campaigns-firebase-analytics-177585
I couldn't find better link. Hopefully that what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/analytics#firebase_ddls_analytics), `APP_FIRST_OPEN` is one of the metrics measured in Dynamic Links. If you want to track different campaigns, the documentation says

> You use Dynamic Links with your existing Google Analytics custom
>   campaigns and iTunes Connect App Analytics campaigns by specifying
>   campaign parameters when you create a Dynamic Link. When a user opens
>   a Dynamic Link with campaign parameters specified, the campaign
>   parameters are passed on to Google Analytics or the App Store.

Comment: What i understood is when you reach appstore, the attributes are stripped. So during `APP_FIRST_OPEN` we don't have the campaign source information. Can you point me to any code examples.